# some reason Cannot read property addEventListener of null

Tags: addeventlistener

I got this error. I tried to dinamicly add some html tags by JS.. And there is a ID name is well what I need for addEventListener. But I dont know how to fix it.. If I change `'#answer-' + i` to `.answers` is working.. But this is not solution because I could click for any button without get the clicked ID..

```
Questions.prototype.displayQuestion = function() {
let answer = [];
questionDOM.innerHTML = this.question;
let correct = this.correct;
for(let i = 0; i < this.answer.length; i++){
    answer.push(
        `
        <div id="answer-${i}" class="answer">
            <h5>${this.answer[i]}</h6>
                <div class="check"></div>
        </div>
        ` 
    );

    document.querySelector('#answer-' + i).addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(i === correct) {
            document.querySelector('#answer-' + correct).classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__heartBeat');
        } else if (i !== correct) {
            document.querySelector('#answer-1').classList.add('animate__animated','animate__headShake')
        }

    })






}
answerDOM.innerHTML = answer.join('');
```

}

index.html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="question">
        <div class="questionbox animate__animated animate__bounce">
            <h2 id="question"></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="answers"></div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing to your answers array but not actually adding the nodes to the dom. You want to do something like document.body.innerHTML += answer[i] before you try to get the element by id. I can also see that your loop won't execute because the length of answer is initially zero before you add to it within the loop. You need to add to answer before the loop or change the loop condition to <= this.answer.length <--- but that is an infinite loop